# Unable to uninstalling managed package from sandbox

Tags: managed-package, uninstall

I facing some issues when uninstalling a managed package from the sandbox. I have removed all the references related (classes, buttons, actions) to that package but still getting the same problem.

Could you please help me out with this.

[image]

Comment: Did you click on Assigned To?  The component type clearly states it's a custom field.  Did you create this field to reference something in the managed package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference of the filed **Assigned To** resides somewhere in code.

If you can not find the field., it is likely due to the field being referenced in a workflow.

To locate workflows potentially preventing the uninstall click into the field's provided name link to view the field's setup section which contains the Object Name field.  An administrator will need to review all workflows built on the field's object to identify, deactivate, and delete workflows that contain references to the field in their evaluation formula or field updates.

If you're unable to locate the references following the instructions above or as outlined in the I am getting errors while uninstalling Managed packages article you can also use the Workbench or Salesforce Extension to Visual Studio Code to download metadata and locate dependencies.

In the metadata, you can search for the **Assigned To** field and then remove the reference.

Comment: Thank you @noor for a reply, as per your suggestion I find the reference, using eclipse editor (dealer__Sales_Up__c.create_appointment.quickAction (2 matches) ) and I have deleted this action but still getting the same problem.

Comment: Did you download all the metadata files ?

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded the metadata and due to the workflow and global picklist, we are not able to uninstall. after removed this reference, the package uninstalled. Thanks, @Noor for your support.